# Can I get a list of the rooms a client is connected to in socket.io?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

What it says at the top - for a given client, can I see what rooms they have joined?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `console.dir(socket);` to see if the data is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a `socket` you can get all the rooms it has joined via `io.sockets.manager.roomClients[socket.id]`.

See [here](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Rooms#rooms-a-client-has-joined).