# Send a message to all rooms a client is connected to

Tags: socket.io, socket.io-1.0

I am using socket.io version 1 and I have the following problem.

I have an application, in which user can connect to different rooms. On disconnect event I want this user to notify that he left the rooms he connected to. (I know that on disconnect user leaves all rooms automatically, but I want to notify others that user left them.)

I looked into [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10099325/1090562) and have not found a simple way to do what I want. May be there is a better way to do this, but currently my solution is to find all rooms and in a loop sent to all people in each room. But neither  [io.sockets.manager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16002883/1090562), nor adapter can give me a list of rooms a client is connected to.

```
client.on('disconnect', function() {
   // io.sockets.manager.roomClients[client.id];
   // io.sockets.adapter.roomClients[client.id];
});
```

**P.S.** Seeing one wrong answer, I want to clarify. I know how to send message to people in the room. I want to solve another problem. If a user entered `Room1`, `Room2`, `...`, `RoomN` and then disconnects, I want to send message to all people in these `N` rooms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find all rooms a client is connected to with `Socket#rooms` object ([documentation](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket#rooms:array)):

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    //...
    console.log(socket.rooms);
});
```

You can then easily send a message to each of these rooms in a loop.

***Caveat:*** `socket.join` method is async, so if you have something like:

```
socket.join('my room name');
console.log(socket.rooms);
```

it won't work as expected. Instead you should write:

```
socket.join('my room name', function() {
    console.log(socket.rooms);
});
```

***Edit:***

If you want to get an array rather than object, you may do this:

```
Object.keys(socket.rooms);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, at the time of this post, the documentation site is down.  Regardless the documentation you refer to is outdated.  It seems the current `socket.rooms` is an object rather than an array.  However we ( may ) also have `socket._rooms` as an array in the future, albeit for less than a month now, from the [current source](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/lib/socket.js#L60). `socket.rooms` has been an object for [over a year](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/1.4.7-pre/lib/socket.js#L58).

Comment: @Nolo yes, this is an object, and it was an object at the time of writing this post. Thanks for the tip. I edited my post to make it more clear